# How to Get Update Last Value in Two Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I Have two table `table1` and `table2`. `table1` some Items and rate `table2` some transactions. I want update `Table2` rate in `Table1`   but `Table2` Many transactions in same Item I want Update Rate Last id 
for example

```
        Table 1
       ItemCode     Name      Rate
      ----------------------------
       101         book         30
       102         pen          10


        Table 2
       Id   ItemCode    Name    Rate
       ------------------------------
        1     101       book     40 
        2     101       book     35    
        3     101       book     20  


      so i want output :
      ItemCode     Name      Rate
      ----------------------------
      101         book         20
      102         pen          10
```

Comment: i wonder why you have two tables for this information.. " Many transactions in same Item I want Update Rate Last id for example" Looks like hard because the Table 1 seams not to have a id column..

Comment: @RaymondNijland the id  used itemcode.   any solution?